Duality between periodic cyclic homology and cohomology
Suppose that $A$ is a (locally convex) unital algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Are there any sufficient conditions for non-degeneracy of the canonical pairing $H^\bullet_\lambda(A) \times H_\bullet^\lambda(A) \to \mathbb{C}$ of (continuous) periodic cyclic cohomology $H^\bullet_\lambda(A)$ and homology $H^\lambda_\bullet(A)$?
For example (unless I'm really missing something), this is true after the fact by Connes–Hochschild–Kostant–Rosenberg for $C^\infty(M)$ when $M$ is a closed manifold and by calculations of Nest and Yashinski for the smooth noncommutative $N$-torus $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^N_\theta)$. Perhaps there's something that can be done with the UCT for local cyclic homology as expounded, for instance, in Meyer's book on local and analytic cyclic homology, but the relationship between the different versions of periodic cyclic (co)homology involved is intimidatingly subtle.
It would be a real bonus if such a sufficient condition could be adapted twisted periodic cyclic homology and cohomology in the sense of Kustermans–Murphy–Tuset, but this may well be too much to hope for.
